# Perform YCSB benchmark on MongoDB atlas

Tags: java, mongodb, benchmarking, mongodb-atlas, ycsb

I would like to measure the performance of MongoDb Atlas with the [YCSB benchmark](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/tree/master/mongodb).
For testing, I first performed the benchmark on ubuntu on a localhost mongo db instance, which works fine, so the benchmark seems to be set up correctly. Now I wanted to benchmark MongoDb in the cloud (MongoDb Atlas), but I am having problems connecting to the server. Since the YCSB benchmark is based on java, I wanted to use the java connection string of my cluster for the benchmark, which is

```
mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.swk7mjl.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

(I have set  and  to my user credentials)

I tried to load the data for the benchmark with the following command:

```
./bin/ycsb load mongodb -s -P workloads/workloada -p mongodb.url=mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.swk7mjl.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority -p mongodb.auth="true" -p recordcount=1000 > outputLoad.txt
```

This generated the following error message:

```
ERROR: Invalid URL: 'mongodb+srv://cluster0.swk7mjl.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true'. Must be of the form 'mongodb://<host1>:<port1>,<host2>:<port2>/database?options'. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/
```

so I left out the `srv` part and tried the command again:

```
./bin/ycsb load mongodb -s -P workloads/workloada -p mongodb.url=mongodb://user:password@cluster0.swk7mjl.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority -p mongodb.auth="true" -p recordcount=1000 > outputLoad.txt
```

But this leads to the following error:

```
Exception while trying bulk insert with 0
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches PrimaryServerSelector. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=cluster0.swk7mjl.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: cluster0.swk7mjl.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster0.swk7mjl.mongodb.net}}]
```

I have also tried a variant with leaving out the credentials in the URL and setting them as the parameters `mongodb.username` and `mongodb.password`:

```
./bin/ycsb load mongodb -s -P workloads/workloada -p mongodb.url=mongodb://cluster0.swk7mjl.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority -p mongodb.username=user -p mongodb.password=password -p mongodb.auth="true" -p recordcount=1000 > outputLoad.txt
```

But this leads to the same error.

In the network access of the MongoDb Atlas cluster, the IP address 0.0.0.0/0 is whitelisted, so access from everywhere should be possible. I can also connect to the cluster via the Mongo shell.

Does anyone has experience with the YCSB benchmark and knows what the correct connection string for the `mongodb.url` parameter is or if I am missing something else?

Comment: The YCSB benchmark seems to rewrite the provided `mongodb.url`.  Perhaps you can follow [the source](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/blob/ce3eb9ce51c84ee9e236998cdd2cefaeb96798a8/mongodb/src/main/java/site/ycsb/db/MongoDbClient.java#L195) and figure out the correct incantation.